# dictionary can't be sorted in Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have been trying lately to learn Cypress and I have to do an exercise. Basically I want to get the prices of a certain product, add them in a dictionary with a key, value pair and then sort that dictionary. I can't find the problem and i am asking you if you can give me some insight.

```
var cardContent = 'div.card-v2-content';
var cardPrice = 'p.product-new-price';
var dict = [];

checkPrices() {

        cy.get(cardContent).each($el => {
            //Loop through each DOM element and find the price of the product
            var eachProductPrice = $el.find(cardPrice);
            var stringPrice = eachProductPrice.text();
            var replacedPrice = stringPrice.replace('.', '').replace('Lei','').replace('de la','').trim();
            var priceNumber = parseFloat(replacedPrice);
            //cy.log(priceNumber)
            
            dict.push($el, priceNumber);


        }).then(() => {

            cy.log('sorting') //Starts the sorting process

            // Create items array
            var items = Object.keys(dict).map(function (key) {
                return [key, dict[key]];
            });

            // Sort the array based on the second element

            var items = (items.push(items.sort(function (first, second) {
                return second[1] - first[1];
            })));


        })
```

Comment: Can you add information about the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: There isn't an error message. at the end of then(() -> {...} inside, is should be a cy.log(dict[0]), which should print the lowest element after the dictionary is sorted. What i get it just an empty log.   it prints log : 'sorting' and below is printing log:

Answer (score 0):

the sorting part should be

```
  // sort is an in place sort, that means that the items will be rearranged
  // just this is ok 
  items.sort(function (first, second) {
       return second[1] - first[1];
  }))
```

look at the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more info on Array.sort